# Koala - how to work with the Koala::Facebook::GraphCollection object?

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api, koala

Koala::Facebook::GraphCollection

by using the search method on the Koala API object, I get a lot of results that I put in a @results variable.

How do I select data from it? for instance, let's take "names"?

using:

```
results.select{ |l| l[/"name"/] }.each
```

but it does not work...

the content of the results is like:

```
{"id"=>"1000000000000", "from"=>{"name"=>"Name Lastname\u0161", "id"=>"1000000000000"}, "message"=> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a hash.

Isn't it just `results["from"]["name"]`?